# Real and imaginary parts of $\cos(z)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Not sure if I have done this correctly, seems too straight forward, any help is very appreciated.

> QUESTION:
>   Find the real and imaginary parts of $f(z) = \cos(z)$.

ATTEMPT:
$\cos(z) = \cos(x+iy) = \cos x\cos(iy) − \sin x\sin(iy) = 
\cos x\cosh y − i\sin x\sinh y$

Is that correct?

Comment: Looks good! So the real and imaginary parts are (...).

Comment: see: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg1Zeg_pDMAhXptoMKHcl2BToQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.edshare.soton.ac.uk%2Fid%2Fdocument%2F5424&usg=AFQjCNF8c8T4Db-jhYY1Pjnb32tbnxjoYQ

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2},\qquad
\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
In particular, for real $y$,
$$
\cos(iy)=\frac{e^{-y}+e^{y}}{2}=\cosh y
$$
and
$$
\sin(iy)=\frac{e^{-y}-e^{y}}{2i}=i\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}=i\sinh y
$$

So, yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, but tis the beauty of the trig/exponential functions! You're $correct$!

Answer (score 1):

Using the exponential definition of the cosine,

$$2\cos(z)=e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=e^{-y+ix}+e^{y-ix}\\
=e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))+e^{y}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))\\
=(e^y+e^{-y})\cos(x)-i(e^y-e^{-y})\sin(x)).$$

Comment: Actually, the question doesn't state clearly what kind of answer is expected, so $\Re(\cos(z))$ and $\Im(\cos(z))$ are equally good !