# How to represent imaginary and real part of $\cos(z)$ as functions of $x$ and $ y$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do i represent imaginary and real part of $ \cos(z) $ as functions of $x$ and $ y$ if $z=x+iy$?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743935/real-and-imaginary-parts-of-cosz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\cos z$ is
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}
$$
If $z=x+iy$, then
$$
e^{iz}=e^{-y}e^{ix}=e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)
$$
Do yourself the missing part.

Alternatively,
$$
\cos(x+iy)=\cos x\cos(iy)-\sin x\sin(iy)
$$
and you can work out the expressions for $\cos(iy)$ and $\sin(iy)$.

Comment: +1 For the Yoda-esque last (edit: second to last) sentence. ;p

Answer (score 0):

The way I like the best is to use the following identities:
$$\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x),\quad \cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$$
and the addition formula for cosine 
\begin{align*}\cos(x+y)& = \cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)\end{align*}
to obtain the identity
$$\cos(x+iy) = \cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y).$$

Of course the same approach works for Sine and Tangens as well.