# Solving a complex trigonometric equation

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\cos(Z)=\frac{3i}{4}$$
I solved it in a weird way by setting $$\cos(Z) = \cos(x+iy) = \cos(x)\cosh(y)-i \sin(x)\sinh(y)$$ and then setting this equal $$\frac{3}{4}i$$ , and since the cosine function has no zero values, then cosine x has to be equal to zero hence $$x= \frac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi n $$ $n= 0, 1, 2,\ldots$, and the same for the imaginary part setting $$\sinh(y)=\frac{3}{4}$$
The problem is I need help solving it the normal way setting $$\cos(Z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

Comment: You will find this question/answers of interest I believe. Seems fine. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743935/real-and-imaginary-parts-of-cosz

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\frac{3i}{4}$$
$$\frac{(e^{iz})^2+1}{2e^{iz}}=\frac{3i}{4}$$
$$2(e^{iz})^2-3ie^{iz}+2=0$$
Solving above quadratic equation for $e^{iz}$
$$e^{iz}=\frac{-(-3i)\pm\sqrt{(-3i)^2-4\cdot 2\cdot 2}}{2\cdot 2}$$
$$e^{iz}=2i, -\frac{i}{2}$$
You can proceed by setting $e^{iz}=e^{-y+ix}=e^{-y}e^{ix}=e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)$

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" way is by setting $cos(z)$ as you defined, then defining $e^{iz}=t$. Multiply by t and you'll get a solvable equation (second degree polynomial in t).

Comment: Is the first method even vaild ?

Comment: Don't think it's worth doing since this is a very simple equation and the "normal" way is so much simpler in terms of algebra and logic. What would you have done if it was $sin(z)$ or a combination of the two?

Comment: yea I would've had problems with that :D